# How to make app "sleep" while Volley is in porgress

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm working on a registration form.
I use Volley to check if an Email already exists (I connect to a PHP file which returns the answer).
My problem is that the app keeps working while I'm still waiting for Volley to return the answer.

Code:

```
        if(isValidEmail(emailET.getText().toString())){
        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    if(success){
                        emailET.setError("Email is already in use");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Happening");
                        validator += "0";
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        EmailCheckRequest emailRequest = new EmailCheckRequest(emailET.getText().toString(), responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AccountEmail.this);
        queue.add(emailRequest);
    }
    System.out.println("validator=" + validator);
    if(validator.matches("00")){
        startActivity(dataCollector());
    }
```

Now the problem is that this part of the code:

```
    if(validator.matches("00")){
    startActivity(dataCollector());
}
```

happens before this part of the code:

```
                    if(success){
                    emailET.setError("Email is already in use");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Happening");
                    validator += "0";
                }
```

How can I make the app "sleep" and continue only after Volley stopped working?

Comment: Just add progressdialog while service calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't sleep the app. Properly wait for Volley by moving the code that performs the checks within the listener, at the end of onResponse